# Change HTTP URL for Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions for Firebase and writing an HTTP trigger. I want to change the function URL from:

https://us-central1-[projectID].cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld

to:

https://us-central1-[projectID].cloudfunctions.net/api/helloWorld

Is that possible?

Comment: The meaning of the question is unclear. Try rewording it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a plain old HTTP function if you want to specify the path of the URL.  You'll have to instead create an Express app and hand that over to Cloud Functions for service.  The code will look something like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/helloWorld', (req, res) => {
    // your function code here
    res.send("hello")
})

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Note that `/api` comes from the name of the export and `/helloWorld` comes from the path in `app.get`.

You will also have to install the [express](https://expressjs.com/) module:

```
npm install express
```